# How use Angularjs expression in spring MVC?

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

i want to create spring mvc form by angularjs ng-repeat.
here is my sample code. but {{$index}} value not valid for spring.

```
   <div ng-repeat="i in list track by $index"> 
     <c:set value="id[{{$index}}]" var="perfix"/> 
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use compile time code in client side and that can not be done.

The `c:set` part is getting parsed when your page is getting compiled, but the `ng-repeat` part is going to run on client system, so there is no `c:set` part to do the job for you.

You must stick to java script world when you are in javascript (client) side